# Generating switch-case function out of State chart

Tags: rhapsody, microc

Although my question is very simple I can't find an answer for it.

I created a class in Rhapsody and associated a statechart to this class but when I generate the code I can't find and code in the class related to the state chart.

Is there any function that needs to be created as a trigger or am I missing something?

my example state chart:
[image]

Comment: Does the model check show any errors?

Comment: No, at all. the code generates with no errors but there is no switch case in it and I can't either find the events. I don't even know where should the switch case be? I mean which function ?

Comment: Can you add a picture of your statechart?

Comment: I added it to the main post. This is a sample project I created to play in away from my actual work

Comment: See the component configuration: Have you configured "Flat" or "Reusable" statecharts?

Comment: I tried both and got the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching for a long while I could find the option that was preventing the generation.

First of all, you need to define a [reactive class](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSB2MU_7.6.1/com.ibm.rhp.cg.doc/topics/rhp_c_cg_reactive_objects.html) to be able to generate a code for a state machine. This point was OK for me and I thought this was only what matters until I found this property [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSB2MU_8.1.1/com.ibm.rhp.cg.doc/topics/rhp_t_dm_genring_ops_stchrt_serial.html):

> The _CG::Statechart::StatechartStateOperations property
> determines whether the code is generated for this feature. The
> possible values for this property are:
>
> **None** (default value) where code is not generated for the feature.
>
> **WithoutReactive** where the product does not generate calls to OMReactive
>
> **WithReactive** where the product generates calls to OMReactive